# How do I iterate through every 2nd element of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to do the equivalent of this Java code in Ruby. What is the best way in Ruby to do the below ? I dont want to use the Ruby for loop , want to follow idiomatic Ruby.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 2) {
    // Do something. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "**step**" method to iterate every 2nd element in the array.

```
(0..array.length).step(2).each do |i|
   puts i
end
```